# Knockout custom binding not updating

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding, bindinghandlers

Please check what I am doing wrong.

The update part of my custom bindinghandler does not executes when I create a control in javascript. I have an Add function that create a row in a table. Controls that are bound to the custom binding does executes the update part but not controls that are subsequently added.

HTML

```
<div id="collapse-programHead" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="cv">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Programme</th>
                            <th>Core Module Count</th>
                            <th>Core SAQA Credit</th>
                            <th>Elective Module Count</th>
                            <th>Elective SAQA Credit</th>
                            <th>Credit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ProgrammeHead">
                        <!-- ko if: isActive -->
                        <tr>
                            <td><select data-bind="options: programmes, optionsText: 'Programme', value: ProgrammeID, optionsValue:'ProgrammeID', optionsCaption:''"></select></td>
                            <td><input type="text" readonly="true" data-bind="value:ModuleCount, offeringCount:$root.programmeOfferingCount"/></td>

                            <td><input type="text"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Credit"/></td>
                            <td class="tinyTD"><a class="removeRow" id="ProgrammeHead" title="Delete item" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></td>
                            <td class="hideTD"><input type="hidden" data-bind="value: CVId" /></td>
                            <td class="hideTD"><input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ProgrammeID" /></td>
                            <td class="hideTD"><input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ProgrammeOfferingID" /></td>
                            <td class="hideTD"><input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ManagementLoadID" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <a title="Add row" id="a2" href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: addRow.bind($data, 'programHead')"><label>Add row</label></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ko.bandingHandler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.offeringCount = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor)
            var id = ko.unwrap(bindingContext.$data.ProgrammeID);

            var item = programmes().filter(function (i) {
                return i.ProgrammeID() == id;
            })
            if (item.length > 0) {
                var count = ko.unwrap(item[0].ProgrammeOfferingCount);
                bindingContext.$data.ModuleCount(count);
            }
        }
    };
```

ProgrammeHead Add

```
self.ProgrammeHead.push({ 'ManagementLoadID': '', 'CVId': '', 'ModuleCount': count, 'ProgrammeID': '', 'ProgrammeOfferingID': '', 'Credit': '', 'isActive': active });
```

Comment: the html was probably a copy/paste deal, but it's invalid as it is; the addRow link will show up after every row, but you also can't put an anchor element at the same level as a `<tr>` element either. Also, your `<tbody>` element isn't closed.

Comment: By definition, the update callback on the custom binding will be call when the bound value changes (in your case $root.programmeOfferingCount changes). I might be wrong but .. it does look like you are using the custom binding for something that is normally done using computed observables. a fiddle would help ...

Comment: @dperry Yes, I  delibritly did not copy all html, however all tags etc in code is valid.

Comment: @Righardt, the tags are not valid; only `<tr>` elements can be children of a `<tbody>` element, you have an `<a>` as a sibling to your `<tr>` in your for-loop.

Comment: @dperry, I know. I only copied part of the html to show the first two `<td>`'s. There are a few more `<td>`'s in the `<tr>`. The `<a>` is outside the `</tbody>` and `</table>` hence the --- The html in visual studio is correct. I will update the html to reflect how the html looks in vs

Answer (score 1):

The `valueAccessor` parameter is a function that returns the bound value. If the bound value is an observable, then you must also "unwrap" the observable to get the real value. In your code, you haven't unwrapped the value properly. It should be:

```
var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

The contents of the `update` function act as the body of a `ko.computed` and so works just like the [computed dependency tracking](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html):

> So, Knockout doesn’t just detect dependencies the first time the evaluator runs - it redetects them every time. This means, for example, that the dependencies can vary dynamically: dependency A could determine whether the computed observable also depend on B or C. Then, it will only be re-evaluated when either A or your current choice of B or C changes. You don’t have to declare dependencies: they’re determined at runtime from the code’s execution.

Comment: value = undefined when I either `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor);` or `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())`. Might this be the root of my problem?

Comment: Since `valueAccessor` is a function, I don't see how it could ever be undefined.